# How to load json from resource_stream in python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pkg-resources

I'm trying to use to use `resource_stream` from `pkg_resources` in conjunction with `json.load` and am having problem in python 3 that were not present in python 2.

When I try to run the following command, I get the error:

```
loaded_json = json.load(resource_stream(__name__, 'path/to/foo.json'))

>> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like in Python 3, `json.load` no longer supports reading from a bytestream, you'll have to decode it before parsing it:

```
json_string = resource_stream(__name__, 'path/to/foo.json').read().decode()
loaded_json = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: This behavior exists in 3.5.2, but not in 3.6.7. Not sure what the exact point-version is where this was fixed, but in 3.6.7, you can use `json.load(resource_stream(...))` without having to read and decode.